# How do you incorporate a restriction of input values in the while loop?

Tags: c

I am currently working on this while loop that I want to only activate if the input is within a defined range that I set. So far I have this but, it's not working the way I want it to..This is the part that I am confident is wrong, since for some reason it doesn't break out of the while loop even if i input numbers beyond the given range >.>.

```
while(result >= -10000 && result <= 10000)
```

Please note that this is just a small portion of my code, once I get the syntax right for the while loop it would be complete :D/

Comment: If you think the code where you input a number into `result` is relevant, you'd be right. How do you *know* the actual value of `result` is what you think it is, and equally important, how do *we* know without seeing the code? There is nothing wrong with that expression., but if `result` doesn't change once it gets past it and into the loop body you think is changing it, it will loop without bound (barring a `break` or `goto`).

Comment: Your confidence is unwarranted. The part that is wrong is certainly in what you're not showing us. Notably, you haven't shown how or when result is set.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the syntax of the `while` loop perfectly right, yet the logic of the condition may be the inverse of what you need: when the `result` becomes *invalid*, your loop will *stop*.

A typical `while` loop use for input has the condition the other way around: it stops when the `result` becomes valid. Also, a common "read until it's correct" loop uses the `do`/`while` construct, like this:

```
do {
    result = ... // read the input into result
    ...
} while (result < -10000 || result > 100000);
```

The *post-condition* of this loop is `(result >= -10000 && result <= 10000)` because this is what is required for the loop to stop iterating. Therefore, the loop stops when `result` becomes valid, which is what input loops are trying to achieve.